# How does LibGDX FitViewport keep aspect ratio after resizing?

Tags: libgdx, resize, viewport, aspect-ratio

I am a little bit confused why my FitViewport is not keeping the aspect ratio when resizing the window.
I thought that it should always keep the aspect ratio and then fill up the screen with black bars for areas which are not used.

However for me it is not keeping the aspect ratio and circles become ellipsis f.e. (see screenshots).

**Code when creating my game renderer (32 and 18 are my world units)**

```
viewport = new FitViewport(32, 18);
camera = viewport.getCamera();
visibleArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight());
scissors = new Rectangle();
```

**Code when resizing the window**

```
 public void resize(int width, int height) {
   Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Resizing to " + width + " x " + height);
   viewport.update(width, height);
   visibleArea.set(0, 0, viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight());
```

**Render method**

```
public void render(float alpha) {
  viewport.calculateScissors(batch.getTransformMatrix(), visibleArea, scissors);
  ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);

  viewport.apply();
  setView(camera.combined, visibleArea.x, visibleArea.y, visibleArea.width, visibleArea.height);

  batch.begin();
  // ...
  batch.end();

  ScissorStack.popScissors();
}
```

[correct aspect ratio on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsCnD.png)

[wrong aspect ratio on resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbPTQ.png)

Comment: Excuse me, I want to ask why you calculateScissors from the `batch.getTransformMatrix` ? I think it should get the current matrix from camera. And then assume your `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera().combined);` is set correctly,  you could try update camera directly from resize and  apply in render to see if it works. The best debugging way is to record the Camera/Viewport value before and after resizing, and see where was wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The scissor thing is taken from the official documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping,-with-the-use-of-scissorstack. That is why I used transform matrix. I will try some more debugging tomorrow but do you see an obvious mistake ? If I set the camera manually then why do I need the viewport in the first place?  

Comment: Sorry, I said **try** because that could be a way to find a problem, maybe I should talk more less.

Comment: Found the solution - thank you for the hints! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the problem actually was with my framebuffer light method (**prepareLightFrameBuffer**) which also had a call to batch.begin(); and batch.end(). 
It seems like this messes up the view (or resets it to something?). To solve the issue I just applied the viewport again and set the view again in the **render** method (Note: I also have a stage so I think that viewport.apply() has to be called here and also in the stage.render() method).

Here is the complete code of the GameRenderer if anyone is interested. I guess somehow it could be simplified but I am no OpenGL/Matrix expert so I have no idea how to do it :)

```
package com.lok.game;

import java.util.Comparator;

import com.badlogic.ashley.core.ComponentMapper;
import com.badlogic.ashley.core.Entity;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapImageLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.tiles.AnimatedTiledMapTile;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ScissorStack;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.lok.game.ecs.components.AnimationComponent;
import com.lok.game.ecs.components.CollisionComponent;
import com.lok.game.ecs.components.MapRevelationComponent;
import com.lok.game.ecs.components.SizeComponent;
import com.lok.game.map.Map;
import com.lok.game.map.Map.Portal;
import com.lok.game.map.MapManager;

public class GameRenderer extends OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer {
private final static String TAG = GameRenderer.class.getName();

private static class yPositionComparator implements Comparator<Entity> {
    private final ComponentMapper<SizeComponent> sizeComponentMapper;

    private yPositionComparator(ComponentMapper<SizeComponent> sizeComponentMapper) {
        this.sizeComponentMapper = sizeComponentMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Entity o1, Entity o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
            } else if (o1 == null) {
            return -1;
            } else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return sizeComponentMapper.get(o1).boundingRectangle.y > sizeComponentMapper.get(o2).boundingRectangle.y ? -1 : 1;
    }

}

private SizeComponent                  cameraLockEntitySizeComponent;
private MapRevelationComponent              cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent;

private Map                          map;
private TiledMapTileLayer                  groundLayer;
private final Array<TiledMapTileLayer>          backgroundLayers;
private final Array<TiledMapTileLayer>          foregroundLayers;
private TiledMapImageLayer                  lightMapLayer;

private final yPositionComparator              entityComparator;

private final ComponentMapper<SizeComponent>      sizeComponentMapper;
private final ComponentMapper<AnimationComponent> animationComponentMapper;

private final Camera                  camera;
private final Viewport                  viewport;
private final Rectangle                  visibleArea;
private final Rectangle                  scissors;

private final ShapeRenderer                  shapeRenderer;

private FrameBuffer                      frameBuffer;
private final AtlasRegion                  lightTexture;
private final AtlasRegion                  shadowTexture;

public GameRenderer() {
    super(null, MapManager.WORLD_UNITS_PER_PIXEL);

    if (Gdx.app.getLogLevel() == Application.LOG_DEBUG) {
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Creating in debug mode");
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        } else {
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Creating in non-debug mode");
        shapeRenderer = null;
    }

    viewport = new FitViewport(32, 18);
    camera = viewport.getCamera();
    visibleArea = new Rectangle();
    scissors = new Rectangle();

    this.backgroundLayers = new Array<TiledMapTileLayer>();
    this.foregroundLayers = new Array<TiledMapTileLayer>();

    this.sizeComponentMapper = ComponentMapper.getFor(SizeComponent.class);
    this.animationComponentMapper = ComponentMapper.getFor(AnimationComponent.class);

    this.entityComparator = new yPositionComparator(sizeComponentMapper);

    final TextureAtlas textureAtlas = AssetManager.getManager().getAsset("lights/lights.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    lightTexture = textureAtlas.findRegion("light");
    shadowTexture = textureAtlas.findRegion("shadow");
    frameBuffer = null;
}

public void setMap(Map map) {
    this.map = map;
    super.setMap(map.getTiledMap());

    this.backgroundLayers.clear();
    this.foregroundLayers.clear();
    this.lightMapLayer = null;
    for (MapLayer mapLayer : map.getTiledMap().getLayers()) {
        if (mapLayer instanceof TiledMapTileLayer) {
            if ("ground".equals(mapLayer.getName())) {
                groundLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) mapLayer;
                } else if (mapLayer.getName().startsWith("background")) {
                backgroundLayers.add((TiledMapTileLayer) mapLayer);
                } else {
                foregroundLayers.add((TiledMapTileLayer) mapLayer);
            }
            } else if (mapLayer instanceof TiledMapImageLayer) {
            lightMapLayer = (TiledMapImageLayer) mapLayer;
        }
    }
}

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Resizing with " + width + "x" + height + " from viewport " + viewport.getScreenWidth() + "x" + viewport.getScreenHeight());
    viewport.update(width, height, false);
    visibleArea.set(0, 0, viewport.getWorldWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight());
    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "To viewport " + viewport.getScreenWidth() + "x" + viewport.getScreenHeight());

    if (frameBuffer != null) {
        frameBuffer.dispose();
    }

    try {
        frameBuffer = FrameBuffer.createFrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight(), false);
        } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        frameBuffer = FrameBuffer.createFrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight(), false);
    }
}

public void lockCameraToEntity(Entity entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        cameraLockEntitySizeComponent = null;
        cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent = null;
        } else {
        cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent = entity.getComponent(MapRevelationComponent.class);
        cameraLockEntitySizeComponent = entity.getComponent(SizeComponent.class);

        if (cameraLockEntitySizeComponent == null) {
            throw new GdxRuntimeException("Trying to lock camera to an entity without size component: " + entity);
        }
    }
}

private void interpolateEntities(float alpha) {
    for (Entity entity : map.getEntities()) {
        final SizeComponent sizeComp = sizeComponentMapper.get(entity);

        final float invAlpha = 1.0f - alpha;
        sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.x = sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.x * invAlpha + sizeComp.boundingRectangle.x * alpha;
        sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.y = sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.y * invAlpha + sizeComp.boundingRectangle.y * alpha;
    }
}

public void render(float alpha) {
    AnimatedTiledMapTile.updateAnimationBaseTime();
    interpolateEntities(alpha);
    map.getEntities().sort(entityComparator);

    if (cameraLockEntitySizeComponent != null) {
        camera.position.set(cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.interpolatedPosition, 0);
        visibleArea.setCenter(cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.interpolatedPosition);
    }

    prepareLightFrameBuffer();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    viewport.apply();
    setView(camera.combined, visibleArea.x, visibleArea.y, visibleArea.width, visibleArea.height);
    batch.begin();
    viewport.calculateScissors(batch.getTransformMatrix(), visibleArea, scissors);
    ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
    if (groundLayer != null) {
        renderTileLayer(groundLayer);
    }
    for (Entity entity : map.getEntities()) {
        renderEntityShadow(entity);
    }
    for (TiledMapTileLayer layer : backgroundLayers) {
        renderTileLayer(layer);
    }
    for (Entity entity : map.getEntities()) {
        renderEntity(entity);
    }
    for (TiledMapTileLayer layer : foregroundLayers) {
        renderTileLayer(layer);
    }
    batch.end();

    applyLightFrameBuffer();

    if (Gdx.app.getLogLevel() == Application.LOG_DEBUG) {
        renderDebugInformation();
    }

    ScissorStack.popScissors();
}

private void renderEntityShadow(Entity entity) {
    final AnimationComponent animationComp = animationComponentMapper.get(entity);

    if (animationComp.animation != null) {
        final SizeComponent sizeComp = sizeComponentMapper.get(entity);
        if (!viewBounds.overlaps(sizeComp.boundingRectangle)) {
            return;
        }

        if (cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent != null && !Intersector.overlaps(cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationCircle, sizeComp.boundingRectangle)) {
            return;
        }

        batch.draw(shadowTexture, sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.x, sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.y - sizeComp.boundingRectangle.height * 0.2f, sizeComp.boundingRectangle.width,
        sizeComp.boundingRectangle.height * 0.5f);
    }
}

private void renderEntity(Entity entity) {
    final AnimationComponent animationComp = animationComponentMapper.get(entity);

    if (animationComp.animation != null) {
        final SizeComponent sizeComp = sizeComponentMapper.get(entity);
        if (!viewBounds.overlaps(sizeComp.boundingRectangle)) {
            return;
        }

        if (cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent != null && !Intersector.overlaps(cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationCircle, sizeComp.boundingRectangle)) {
            return;
        }

        final TextureRegion keyFrame = animationComp.animation.getKeyFrame(animationComp.animationTime, true);
        batch.draw(keyFrame, sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.x, sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.y, sizeComp.boundingRectangle.width, sizeComp.boundingRectangle.height);
    }
}

private void prepareLightFrameBuffer() {
    if (cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent != null) {
        frameBuffer.begin();

        final Color mapBackgroundColor = map.getBackgroundColor();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(mapBackgroundColor.r, mapBackgroundColor.g, mapBackgroundColor.b, mapBackgroundColor.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        setView(camera.combined, visibleArea.x, visibleArea.y, visibleArea.width, visibleArea.height);
        batch.begin();
        if (lightMapLayer != null) {
            batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);
            renderImageLayer(lightMapLayer);
        }

        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);
        final Rectangle boundingRectangle = cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.boundingRectangle;
        batch.draw(lightTexture, cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.interpolatedPosition.x + boundingRectangle.width * 0.5f - cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationRadius, // x
        cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.interpolatedPosition.y + boundingRectangle.height * 0.5f - cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationRadius, // y
        cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationRadius * 2f, cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationRadius * 2f);

        batch.end();

        frameBuffer.end();
    }
}

private void applyLightFrameBuffer() {
    if (cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent != null) {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix().idt());
        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_SRC_COLOR);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), -1, 1, 2, -2);
        batch.end();
    }
}

private void renderDebugInformation() {
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);

    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    for (Rectangle rect : map.getCollisionAreas()) {
        shapeRenderer.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }

    for (Entity entity : map.getEntities()) {
        final CollisionComponent collisionComponent = entity.getComponent(CollisionComponent.class);
        final SizeComponent sizeComp = sizeComponentMapper.get(entity);
        if (collisionComponent != null) {
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
            shapeRenderer.rect(sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.x + collisionComponent.rectOffset.x, sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.y + collisionComponent.rectOffset.y,
            collisionComponent.collisionRectangle.width, collisionComponent.collisionRectangle.height);
        }

        if (sizeComp != null) {
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            shapeRenderer.rect(sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.x, sizeComp.interpolatedPosition.y, sizeComp.boundingRectangle.width, sizeComp.boundingRectangle.height);
        }

    }

    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (Portal portal : map.getPortals()) {
        shapeRenderer.rect(portal.getArea().x, portal.getArea().y, portal.getArea().width, portal.getArea().height);
    }

    if (cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent != null) {
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        shapeRenderer.circle(cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.interpolatedPosition.x + cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.boundingRectangle.width * 0.5f,
        cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.interpolatedPosition.y + cameraLockEntitySizeComponent.boundingRectangle.height * 0.5f,
        cameraLockEntityRevelationComponent.revelationCircle.radius, 64);
    }

    shapeRenderer.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Disposing Gamerenderer");
    super.dispose();
    if (shapeRenderer != null) {
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
    }
    if (frameBuffer != null) {
        frameBuffer.dispose();
    }
}
}
```